# date/time and data counts on same line in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to edit my code to give me current date and time and then some data counts on the same line. I have attached the java code below.

```
if(tglbtnWrite.isSelected() && (intervalCounter%requiredParams[2] == 0))

                        printw.printf(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + ","); //For every new line of counts, shows current date and and time of the system.
                    r.write(POLL_FLAG_ADDRESS,0); // put it back down
                    intervalCounter++; // increment interval counter (gets reset by GO/STOP toggle)
                    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_WIDGETS; i++) { // loop through all widgets
                        NumWidget tmp = numwid.get(i);
                        if((tmp.getState() != 0) && (tmp.getState() != 16)) { // check if widget is configured for a channel
                            tmp.setAcc(tmp.getAcc() + r.read(translate[tmp.getState() - 1])); // if it is, poll the respective register
                            if(intervalCounter%requiredParams[2] == 0) { // check if we have reached integration interval                                   
                                tmp.setTextFieldText(String.format("%,d", tmp.getAcc())); // if so, update display
                                if(tglbtnWrite.isSelected()) 
                                    //s.append(tmp.getAcc()+ ","); // if write enabled, write to disk
                                    printw.printf(tmp.getAcc()+ ",");
                                    tmp.setAcc(0); // reset accumulator


                            }


                        }
```

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Instead I am getting:

[image]

The idea is that I want a date and time stamp for each line of data and that is what is the second line is for.

What edit should I make?

EDIT: I removed the screenshot and posted code snippet.

Comment: Use `print()` instead of `printf()` in if block. Might help you.

Comment: I did try that, and nothing happened, actually.

Comment: Remove `"\r\n"`. It's what starts a new line of output.

Comment: Post source code as text, not image.

Comment: Please use code blocks and only post the code you want to ask about (printing something), there is a lot of redundant code here which is irrelevant to the question. 

There is also a bit missing context. What is exactly `printw` and `dtf`? I can pretty much guess that `printw` is of type `PrintStream` and `dtf` is of type `DateTimeFormat`, but it will make it much easier for people to answer your questions correctly right away, without having to do some assumptions and guessing about variables' declarations and instantiations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a StringBuffer to build out your string and then do a printf on the end result

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + ",");
// Add your other items with sb.append()
// When done write out the end result
printw.printf(sb.toString());
```

Also as Andreas mentioned in the comment, you should remove the \r\n from your intermediate appends and only have them at the end.

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you are printing `"\r\n"` (Which is the new line character in Windows: [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation)) on every widget in your loop. Therefore, it will break the line after every single widget.

If you want to only break the line after **all** the widgets were printed. You changed the print statement in your loop to:

```
// This will not break the lines after every widget.
printw.printf(tmp.getAcc() + ",");
```

Then outside your loop, you should add

```
printw.println(); 
// This will print a line break appropriate to the system you are running
// your application on, regardless if it's windows or not.
```

source of [PrintStream#println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println())

Comment: It did not help. Now, I have date and time stamp on top and then two line breaks and then the counts in three different lines and then again two line breaks....

Comment: Are you sure you print the line break outside after the widgets' loop? and that you have removed the new line character `"\r\n"` from your in-loop print statement?

Comment: Yes, I rechecked again.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with a code snippet (using Markdown code blocks instead of a screenshot) of how your code snippet currently looks?

Comment: Hi @Hesham, I did that. And this still does not work.